# Filter Dimension Members that don't have any Measure Values

Tags: filter, ssas, member, dimension

I have a straight up question about the SSAS
Is it possible to filter out Dimension Members that have no Values in Measures?

[image: here is my Problem]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your image looks like you are browsing using Excel. Drop-down boxes in Excel show all dimension members. You can write MDX to populate SSRS or other reporting application drop-downs with only values that are tied to a measure or measure group using Exists or NonEmpty, but Excel doesn't have a way to do this. If you are never going to have data before 7/1/2007, you can use a view or named query to only bring dates from that day forward into your cube. If you use slicers instead of drop-down boxes in Excel, it is easier to see which dimension members have no data.